# Removing cells/rows that don't contain regex match with Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a csv of a single column containing supposedly phone numbers.  However, there are several cells containing the wrong number of digits, alphabet and symbols, etc.  I just want to keep every row whose cell contains exactly ten numerical digits and delete all other rows.

I also have a file that includes a weird non-ascii character in the middle of every cell in the name column (after the first name).  Is there a simple way to discard every non-ascii character in a file?  I just want to get rid of it, though replacing it with a space would be fine, too.

I already have pandas imported in the code I'm running on my csvs, so if that helps, it's available.

Comment: Just use a filter: `new_li=[e for e in old_old_li if re.search(regex, e)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's generate some random phone numbers -- most will be good, some bad:

```
import random

li=[]
for i in range(50):
    li.append('{}-{}-{}'.format(random.randrange(1,999), random.randrange(1,999), random.randrange(100,9999)))
```

Then filter those:

```
import re
new_li=[e for e in li if re.match(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d', e)]

print new_li
print set(li)-set(new_li)    # show the ones removed...
```

If you *want* to do it Pandas, you can use the same regex and use `.apply` to the DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(li, columns=['Phone'])
pat=re.compile(r'^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$')
print df
print df[df['Phone'].apply(lambda s: bool(pat.search(s)))]
```

Comment: Perfect!  I love when people actually show me the process behind the answer so that I can learn.